# Redirect OkHttp3 requests on a specific network

Tags: android, networking, okhttp

When I have timeouts on the WiFi, I try to redirect the traffic on the mobile connection. To perform that I use a `NetworkRequest` and ask for `TRANSPORT_CELLULAR`, it gives me a `Network` object and I try to use it with OkHttp3.

My initial (not binded to network) OkHttp instance is instantiate like that :

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .sslSocketFactory(mSSLSocketFactory, new MyTrustManager())
    .dns(mNetworkDns)
    .hostnameVerifier(new MyHostnameVerifier());
```

with my SSLSocketFactory `createSocket` method like that :

```
  @Override
  public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String s, int i, boolean flag) throws IOException {
    if (mNetwork != null) {
      if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Socket bindedSocket = mNetwork.getSocketFactory().createSocket(s, i);
        return mFactory.createSocket(bindedSocket, s, i, flag);
      }
    }
    return mFactory.createSocket(socket, s, i, flag);
  }
```

and the Dns lookup like that :

```
  @Override
  public List<InetAddress> lookup(String hostname) throws UnknownHostException {
    if (mNetwork != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      List<InetAddress> addresses = Arrays.asList(mNetwork.getAllByName(hostname));
      Log.i("NetworkDns", "List : " + addresses);
      return addresses;
    }
    return SYSTEM.lookup(hostname);
  }
```

If the network is not set, it is working.
But if at one moment I pass a Network object to my SSLSocketFactory and my DNS, I only got timeouts : D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

I put few breakpoints in createSocket and lookup methods and they seem to work correctly, using the network object they should use.
Any idea how I can fix or progress on this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it seems that the `createSocket` from `SSLSocketFactory` should not be used this way. I finally made it work by adding a standard `SocketFactory` binded to my network to my `OkHttpClient` instance.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .socketFactory(myNetwork.getSocketFactory())
    .sslSocketFactory(mSSLSocketFactory, new MyTrustManager())
    .dns(mNetworkDns)
    .hostnameVerifier(new MyHostnameVerifier());
```

And finally I do not override the createSocket method in my `SSLSocketFactory`. This way sockets are binded to my network, even SSL ones.